# Pass multiple parameters to $http.post?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I am trying to do a post request to save data in the server using the following url:

```
url = /api/projects/:projectId/scenarios/:scenarioId
```

I want to pass projectId and scenarioId. How can I do that using $http.post?

Comment: That's just a URL - what angularJS code have you tried to use that hasn't worked for you? The documentation is pretty clear   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

Comment: Pass a parameter object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use $resource (more powerful than $http)

Even better with a service or factory.

```
angular.module('MyApp.services').
factory('Project_Resource',["$resource", function ($resource){
    var baseUrl = "/api/projects/";
    return  $resource(baseUrl+':projectId',{}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        get:   { method: 'GET' } ,
        getScenarios : {method: 'GET',url:baseUrl+':projectId/scenarios/:scenarioId',isArray: true},
    });
}]);
```

....
And inside a controller (don't forget to declare Project_Resource)

```
var projectIdParam = 5;
var scenarioIdParam = 15;
Project_Resource.getScenarios({projectId:projectIdParam, scenarioId: scenarioIdParam}, 
  function (data) {   //success
      //Store data in variable          
  },
  function (data) {   //failure

  });
```